# jQuery append content on multiple code rows

Tags: jquery, append

I'm appending large blocks of HTML with jquery .append().

This works:

```
 $('#Ctabs1-pane' + index + '').append('<br /><br /><br />');
```

I would like this to work

```
$('#Ctabs1-pane' + index + '').append('<br />
<br />
<br />
');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate those strings,

```
$('#Ctabs1-pane' + index + '').append('<br />' +
'<br />' +
'<br />' 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
$('#Ctabs1-pane' + index + '').append('<br />\
<br />\
<br />\
');
```

you can add `\` at end of every row.